# How to install lower version of laravel?

Tags: laravel

trying to install new laravel app I got version error :

```
$ laravel new hostels3
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for mockery/mockery 1.4.1 -> satisfiable by mockery/mockery[1.4.1].
    - mockery/mockery 1.4.1 requires php ^7.3 || ^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

I do not want to move to PHP 7.3 now and if there isa a way to install lower version of laravel
to satisfy my PHP version 7.2.24 ? If yes, how ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel installer [needs PHP 7.3](https://github.com/laravel/installer/blob/d3edd2a49e7be27d9d300e6ed951f65da4278549/src/NewCommand.php#L44), You may use `composer` instead:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel hostels3
```

Note 1: Laravel framework v7.x needs PHP version 7.2.5 or greater. You have 7.2.24 so you can install Laravel 7.x (the latest as of writing).

Note 2: To install older version of Laravel, specify the version as the last argument:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel hostels3 "6.*"
```

Answer (score 1):

that way you can choose the version to install

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel miproyecto "6.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

using composer you can simply install, Below I show laravel 5.4 install using composer

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.4.*"
```